# Magento 2 Backend Customer Add Address After Generate Error " One or more input exceptions have occurred."

Tags: magento2, backend, customer-address

Admin Side Create Customer Successfully then Add Address After Generate Error " One or more input exceptions have occurred."

I Want to Save Customer Address without First Name of customer.

Thank You..

Comment: Please put the error message also here & also check your system.log & exception.log files.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lizmfg

Comment: thank you for quick response .i want to save customer address save without first name of customer.

Comment: I think you need to change your admin password first & then again need to try with this customer creation & address change. As you can see into the image you provided here the system is asking for the password change so It might be the issue with that try after changing your admin password & if still facing any issue put that also here along with your question! Happy to help!

Comment: already done but still error available.

Comment: What is your exception.log file says about this?